# I am looking for a way to cluster spatial data in a balanced way

Tags: optimization, cluster-analysis, data-analysis, spatial, arcgis

My input data is 1000 points, each of which has a profit column and a longitude and latitude column. I want to do clustering in such a way that it takes almost the same time to travel the distance between the points of each class and also the total profit of the points in each class is almost the same, I also have the matrix of the time distance between the points, how can I do this?

I used the grouping analysis tool in ARC GIS, but it does not answer this problem